# Simple software authentication for a C# app?

Tags: c#, php, .net, licensing

I want the people who uses my software not to be able to send copies of the app to other people. What I'm thinking I could to is use private/public key encryption this way: send the user an activation code that I would keep in a database in a web server. Then, the first time the user runs the app it would send to the server the code + some info about his hardware. Then I would take that information as it would be an encrypted string and decrypt it with a private key in the server, and send the decrypted string back to the user. The app would store this string and encrypt it with a public key every time the app runs and the app would check that it matches the hardware info + his code. But I'm guessing there is a simpler way to do this. I really don't need that much security. Any suggestion?

**Edit:** Actually my public/private keys trick is not going to work at all. Mathematically...

Comment: Why is it not going to work? It sounds fine.

Comment: Whatever licensing scheme you use, make sure you also use obfuscation on your assemblies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be very difficult to protect a C# application. I would put together something trivial (send a message to the server with some unique identifying details, if it's different send back an "unauthorized" message). Anyone with decent skills will probably be able to open the MSIL and cut out the authorization check bits, so I wouldn't spend too much time on it.

Answer (score 0):

actually, create serialized variable and save it on the computer when the program starts up, since its its first run, the file would be missing, if its missing, then fire it to the server that its a new user, and it would create the serialized file, afterwards, if its not the first time, the serialized file would be loaded blocking the user interface, hiding the serialized file is easy, since microsoft has many folders, this would be much easier, since the user's trafic to the server would be minimal and would only happen one time.. it would only happen when it fires up the query letting the program know its not the first time it was open...

and the identity of the computer is constant.. since the serialized file may be unique.. its up to you how to make it unique...